# Python-Converting binary to decimal

Tags: python, binary, decimal

Im doing a colledge assignment which is have us create a python program to  convert binary to decimal without using the bin() function or list(). I'm plan to have each 1's and 0's stored in a function which will be multiplied later. However, I'm not sure how am i suppose to do so

Comment: Have a read about the process. Imagine how you would convert the a small number, then a slightly larger one and build up from there

Comment: Converting isnt the problem that im having, is the storing of the binary numbers is the problem

Comment: @Ruben a number is a number (it'd always be stored in binary per se, on a machine). So you might be actually thinking about storing its base-2 representation. What about storing it as string?

Comment: Are you sure that you've described the assignment correctly? There'd be no point using the built-in `bin()` function here, since it converts decimal to binary.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could pass the binary number as a string, and iterate over it in reverse order, multiplying each 0 or 1 by 2^n, where n is a number incremented at each loop cycle.

```
def bin2dec(b):
    number = 0
    counter = 0
    for i in b[::-1]: # Iterating through b in reverse order
        number += int(i)*(2**counter)
        counter += 1

    return number

bin2dec("101010") # 42
```

**EDIT :** Like Byte Commander did, you could also use enumerate in the loop instead of a manuel counter, it serve the same purpose.

```
def bin2dec(b):
    number = 0
    for idx, num in enumerate(b[::-1]): # Iterating through b in reverse order
        number += int(num)*(2**idx)

    return number
```

Comment: you could use enumerate() instead of the manual counter variable.

Comment: I did it the simple way so it can be understood easily, but your one-liner is more efficient

Comment: Your for loop is fine, but `enumerate(b)` would have been the way you should use in real code, it's much cleaner and easier than manually taking care of a counter variable.

Comment: I know, but for some college assignment where the goal is to understand the algorithm I made it clearer this way, at least I hope

Comment: I never actually thought about that, i always assumed that python would just multiply the entire binary value (where 101001 x 2^2 etc). Also, can you clarify what does the def(b) function do?

Comment: It sets the `number` variable to 0. Loops through the binary number in reverse order _(for 101010 -> 010101)_. Multiplies 2^(position in the binary number) per 0 or 1. Add that result to the `number` variable and returns it at the end. _(here it does 0*1 + 1*2 + 0*4 + 1*8 + 0*16 + 1*32 = 42)_

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reverse the bit string, or use indices. You can use bitwise operators for this simple transformation.

Here's some Python 2 / Python 3 code:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def bin_to_dec(bits):
    n = 0
    for b in bits:
        n = (n << 1) | (b == '1')
    return n

# Test

for i in range(16):
    bits = format(i, 'b')
    n = bin_to_dec(bits)
    print('{0:2}: {1:>4} {2:2}'.format(i, bits, n))
```

**output**

```
 0:    0  0
 1:    1  1
 2:   10  2
 3:   11  3
 4:  100  4
 5:  101  5
 6:  110  6
 7:  111  7
 8: 1000  8
 9: 1001  9
10: 1010 10
11: 1011 11
12: 1100 12
13: 1101 13
14: 1110 14
15: 1111 15
```

This works because `False` has the arithmetic value of zero, and `True` has the arithmetic value of one, so in an arithmetic expression `(b == '1')` behaves like 1 if `b` equals `'1'` and 0 otherwise.

If you don't feel comfortable using the `<<` left bit shift and `|` bitwise OR operators, you can use multiplication and addition instead. Simply replace

```
n = (n << 1) | (b == '1')
```

with

```
n = (n * 2) + (b == '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple one-liner using list comprehension:

```
decimal = sum(int(bit) * 2**rank for rank, bit in enumerate(reversed(binary)))
```